# Как сделать такие блоки (Портфолио)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Недавно на каком то сайте увидел такой пример (Портфолио), мне понравилось,пожалуйста подскажите как это делается. Скриншот внизу.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сначала рисуется дизайн, потом макет, потом верстается по макету.

Comment: а как потом сделать через js ?

Comment: Используйте плагин - http://masonry.desandro.com/ или http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ с masonry grid

Comment: Надо зайти на "какой-то сайт" http://genshtab.by/portfolio/ и посмотреть в коде страницы, как это сделано там, а потом повторить у себя. Вы бы отредактировали вопрос, а то непонятно, что имеется в виду под словами "как это делается?" - делается что?

Comment: Спасибо всем за ответ !!

Answer (score 1):

**Вариант 1:**

```css
.flexboxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height:200px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.flexboxes > div {width:200px;background-color:red;margin:3px;}
.block0 {height: 60px;}
.block1 {height: 80px;}
.block2 {height: 70px;}
.block3 {height: 90px;}
.block4 {height: 80px;}
.block5 {height: 100px;}
```

```html
<div class="flexboxes">
  <div class="block0"></div>
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
  <div class="block3"></div>
  <div class="block4"></div>
  <div class="block5"></div>
</div>
```

**Вариант 2 (с использованием скриптов):**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.flexboxes').masonry({
    itemSelector: 'div' // обращаемся к пунктам
  });
});
```

```css
.flexboxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height:200px;
  width: 630px;
}
.flexboxes > div {width:200px;background-color:red;margin:3px;}
.block0 {height: 60px;}
.block1 {height: 80px;}
.block2 {height: 70px;}
.block3 {height: 90px;}
.block4 {height: 80px;}
.block5 {height: 100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>

<div class="flexboxes">
  <div class="block0"></div>
  <div class="block2"></div>
  <div class="block4"></div>
  <div class="block1"></div>
  <div class="block3"></div>
  <div class="block5"></div>
</div>
```